# Google Maps v2 - Collapsing Turn-by-Turn List

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-2

I'm opening the built-in android map app as follows

```
string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=a@saddr=LatLng&daddr=" + query;

Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the turn-by-turn directions list collapsed when the map is brought up ?

So far I've tried

```
"&iwd=0"
"&om=0"
```

with no luck.  Is this even possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: Even if it would be possible, bear in mind that the Maps application does not have to honor any particular query parameter, and so what works today may not work tomorrow. Relying upon undocumented effects like these is asking for long-term trouble.

Comment: @CommonsWare Noted. I'm eventually going to include a MapActivity or MapFragment into my app (technical details currently preventing). Your argument is exactly why I want to use the API methods, and not these query strings, but I cant for now. (I'm using setClassName b/c I couldn't craft a directions-query using the geo: scheme). Thanks!